# If $_POST is empty function

Tags: php, forms, function

I am creating a form where I am using $_POST php function.

Here is how my form looks like.

**form.php**

```
<h1>Songs Movies Form</h1>
<hr />

<form action="songs-movies.php" method="post">

Song Name:
Enter Song Name: <input type="text" name="SongName" size="25" />

Enter Movie Name: <input type="text" name="MovieName" size="25" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />

</form>

<br />
<a href="/forms/">Back to Forms</a>
<hr />
```

Now I want to display result of **SongName** and **MovieName**, so I used **echo $_POST["SongName"];** and **echo $_POST["MovieName"];** which generates the result perfectly.

Now I want to put these values **SongName** and **MovieName** between the text/line/para in the result/output page and if the value of **SongName** or **MovieName** is empty then the result/output should not display that specific text/line/para where I have put those functions.

**e.g.**

---

**ABC Song** is the popular Song of the **XYZ Movie**. The **ABC Song** of **XYZ Movie** is directed by PQR Director.

---

Now you can see there are two sentences in the above Para. I want to put the function for the first sentence only when the field values of **SongName** and **MovieName** are empty then

- It should display the first sentence whether the field values of **SongName** and **MovieName** is empty or not i.e. *ABC Song is the popular Song of the XYZ Movie*. If the field values of **SongName** and **MovieName** are empty then it can leave blank space between them and I know it can be done through this function **echo $_POST["SongName"];**.

BUT

- It should not display the first sentence line if the field values of **SongName** and **MovieName** are empty i.e. *The ABC Song of XYZ Movie is directed by PQR Director.*

Comment: You can check if `$_POST['key']` is set with `isset($_POST['key'])` and then do whatever you like.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
if(!empty($_POST['foo'])) {
   echo "a sentence".$_POST['foo']." with something in the middle.";
}
```

This will check that the value is NOT empty, however empty means a lot of things in PHP so you may need to be more specific. For example you may want to check simple if its set:

```
if(isset($_POST['foo'])) {
   echo "a sentence".$_POST['foo']." with something in the middle.";
}
```

Comment: I already tried `if(isset($_POST['foo'])) {` but it was not working.

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['foo'])) {` it seems to work what I wanted.

Comment: Just checking, you did replace foo with your actual variable name yes?

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['foo'])) {
   echo "a sentence".$_POST['foo']." with something in the middle.";
}` this worked for me. Thanks I wanted the same.

Comment: I replaced "foo" with the variable SongName and it is working exactly I wanted.

Comment: Can you help me in this question related to the above question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305486/wordpress-front-end-form-to-publish-draft-posts-directly

Answer (score 2):

You really confused me with the last 2-3 sentences.
What you want to do can be accomplished by using if, elseif and else control structures.

```
if ($_POST['MovieName'] AND $_POST['SongName']) 
{
    //code
}  
elseif ($_POST['MovieName'])
{
    //code
}  
elseif ($_POST['SongName']) 
{
    //code
}  
else 
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: `empty()` is safer than evaluating as a boolean, since the implicit `isset()` prevents the `E_NOTICE` from being raised if variable is completely undefined.

Comment: `if(!empty($_POST['foo'])) {
   echo "a sentence".$_POST['foo']." with something in the middle.";
}` this worked for me. Thanks I wanted the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in three ways.

1. ```
   if(isset($_POST['value1']))
   {
       //...
   }
   ```
2. ```
   if(!empty($_POST['value1'])) 
   {
       //...
   }
   ```
3. and the simple way

   ```
   if($_POST('value1')=="")
   {
       ....
   }
   ```

I sometimes use the third way when i'm confused with form submitting, but of course the first and the second are more elegant!