# If $_POST is empty Multiple function

Tags: php, post, if-statement

I have the following $_POST function to check if the fields of 'start', 'middle' and 'end' is empty or not.

```
if(!empty($_POST['start'])) {
   $description = "a sentence".$_POST['start']." with something in the START.";
}

if(!empty($_POST['middle'])) {
   $description = "a sentence".$_POST['middle']." with something in the MIDDLE.";
}

if(!empty($_POST['end'])) {
   $description .= "a sentence".$_POST['end']." with something in the END.";
}
```

I want to check the values in one function, in other words I want to check multiple values at the same time. I have seen few method but not sure which one is right, using **comma** or **&&** or **||**, something like below ...

```
if(!empty($_POST['start']) , (!empty($_POST['middle']) , (!empty($_POST['end']))
```

or

```
if(!empty($_POST['start']) && (!empty($_POST['middle']) && (!empty($_POST['end']))
```

or

```
if(!empty($_POST['start']) || (!empty($_POST['middle']) || (!empty($_POST['end']))
```

Can anyone tell me the right code for this kind of formation?

Comment: Can these values come together? Or always one/none?

Comment: the && will check every condition and if all are true it will return true... THe || will check the first condition if its true it will return true else check the second condition If all are false(not even a single is true) it will return false.... and if you , - then the last condition to the right will be evaluated and if it is true then it will return true else false.

Comment: Have you tried your different methods to see what happens when you run them?

Comment: well I saw these **comma** or **&&** or **||** functions somewhere but I don't know how to use them in the function when I use them in the way given above it gives me Syntax error, what is the right way to use them, does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here are some basic.. i made it as a comment(as i was not sure if this is the thing you asked for) but i guess an answer would be appropriate with a bit of details.

- the AND operatior

the && will check every condition and if all are true it will return true...

take it like this

```
if(FALSE && TRUE)
```

it will always return False and if will not execute  because one of the condition is false

- The OR operator

THe || will check the first condition if its true it will return true else check the second condition If all are false(not even a single is true) it will return false.

again following the previous example

```
if(TRUE || False || False)
```

now the compiler checks the first condition if its true it will ignore the next two conditions and return true.

`if(FALSE || FALSE || FALSE)`  - this will return false as all are false

- THe comma Operator

if you **,** operatior then the last condition to the right will be evaluated and if it is true then it will return true else false

example

```
if(True,True,True,False)  -  it will return false

if(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) - it will return true
```

so choose the operator according to your logic.

USE THIS :

```
if((!empty($_POST['start'])) && (!empty($_POST['start'])) && (!empty($_POST['start'])));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaining it, but I'm still confused. I want to check three values **'start'**, **'middle'**, **'end'** if all of these functions exist then pass the value otherwise leave it empty. Which option is will fit to my condition?

Comment: use AND (&&) as it will check each and every condition.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the function I was looking for.

`if(empty($_POST['start']) && empty($_POST['middle']) && empty($_POST['end']))`

I was using **!empty** with **&&** but it was giving syntax error when I replaced **!empty** with **empty**, it stopped giving syntax error, so I hope it will work.

Comment: @user1444345 use this 
if((!empty($_POST['start'])) && (!empty($_POST['start'])) && (!empty($_POST['start'])));

Comment: Thanks, it is working too. I think the problem was not due to **!empty** ... it was the bracket **()** problem, by adding number of brackets it removes the syntax error.

Comment: my solution is more elegant :)

Answer (score 2):

Your looking for something like:

```
// Establish valid post key values
$valid_post_variables = array_flip( ['start', 'middle', 'end'] );

// Fetch post data
$post = $_POST;

// $result will contain the values of post where the keys matched valid
$result = array_intersect_key( $post, $valid_post_variables );

// if the resulting array contains our 3 options, its go time
if ( count( $result ) == 3 ) {
     //start middle and end where all passed via POST
}
```

Comment: I don't think so, it looks like a different thing. I have the processing functions already, I just want to check multiple value at the same time using a single statement of 'if'.

Comment: the result will be an array containing valid post options,

Answer (score 0):

```
function insertPost($before, $offset, $after)
{
    if(!empty($_POST[$offset])) {
         return $before . $_POST[$offset] . $after;
    }
    return '';
}

$description = insertPost('a sentence', 'start', ' with something in the START.');
```